# How to install custom kernel from source? - Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 (GT-P5113)

Tags: installation, kernel, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I have modified the kernel code in attempts to add a driver for USB to Ethernet. I have successfully compiled the code and am trying to install it onto my tablet. I am following the README that came with the source code provided by Samsung (making a .tar for the zImage file), but when I try installing it with Odin it gives me an installation error. Alternatively, I have tried making a zip file and installing with CWM and it again fails.

I am thinking that I am missing some files needed to perform the installation. What else besides zImage do I need?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're on Linux.

If the zImage already has a ramdisk in it (check by using [unmkbootimg](http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Unmkbootimg) and confirming if you get initramfs.cpio.gz after decompiling), rename it to boot.img and do this in a terminal (Odin way):

```
tar -H ustar -c boot.img > boot.tar
```

Or you can look for an existing kernel for your device, download the flashable ZIP for it, replace the boot.img inside with yours, then flash in CWM.